# I cant let the container be responsive when i hit toggle device in chrome dev tool

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I am doing a homework problem. And for this part, I need to make the container have a normal margin in computer view, and after toggle the device in chrome devTool, it has to be full width. I will upload screenshots to clarify that.

[normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxDKb.jpg)

[toggle view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLcCo.jpg)

[answer normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTTSG.png)

[answer toggle view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9qgk.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="store.css">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Store Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="navbar" style="  background-color: yellow;">
            <li><a href="http://csc412sfsu.com/~yzhang25/store_home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://csc412sfsu.com/~yzhang25/store_hours">Hours</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://csc412sfsu.com/~yzhang25/store_about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--<div style="background-color: #FCDFBB; max-width: 800px; margin:auto; height: 90vh">-->
        <div class="container" style="background-color: #FCDFBB; height: 90vh; margin: 
        auto;">
            <h1>Yiyu's Store</h1>
            <p>
                This is my personal store, it will sell some of my personal stuffs. <br>
                Hope you guys love it!<br>
                Also, I sell some small pets here, cute pet only! <br>
            </p>
            <p>
                Another paragraph lol <br>
                It will show with different color <br>
            </p>
            <p>This is the unordered thist that I'm displaying on this page</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Great service</li>
                <li>Long hours</li>
                <li>Quality products</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--</div>-->

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to think of things in the reverse order: moving from smaller screens to larger ones. This is a tried-and-true workflow (of course there are exceptions) for designing and implementing screen designs that need to work on mobile devices on up to desktop resolutions.

This overview may be helpful: https://zellwk.com/blog/how-to-write-mobile-first-css/

The `body` tag will, by default, fill the available width of the window unless it is constrained (you will probably want to add `margin: 0` to the `body` element to ensure there is no gapping along the edges). Inside your `body` tag, I would recommend wrapping all of your content inside a `main` tag (unless your homework assignment specifically prohibits it). `main` is a block-level element and will stretch to fill all the available horizontal space of its parent (in this base, the `body` element).

So, you get the mobile ("toggled") view stretching to the edges basically for free. It works out of the box.

**Non-Bootstrap**

At larger screen sizes (e.g., desktops), you'll want to constrain the width of your `main` element with a `max-width` declaration (via a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)) and set its right and left margins to `auto`. This will horizontally center the `main` element.

In its most basic form, this would looks something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) { 
    main {
        max-width: 1024px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}
```

**Breaking it down (non-Bootstrap)**

Here, we're saying that at all window widths equal to or greater than `1200px`, we want to apply a CSS rule that constrains the maximum width of `main` to be only `1024px`. (I'm just pulling these values out of a hat; feel free to change them to suit your needs). And we want it centered in the viewport, so we'll tell the left and right margins to expand inwards from the right and left edges automatically until they reach the `main` element.

**Bootstrap**

Looks like you're using Bootstrap 4.0.0, so you have access to Bootstrap's flexbox-powered grid system. With BS's utility classes, accomplishing this layout can be done pretty easily. How you choose to do it will depend on how you've configured Bootstrap (and how you choose to use Bootstrap), but out of the box, you could do something as simple as this:

```
<body>
  <main class="container-fluid"> 
    <div class="row justify-content-lg-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
        <!-- content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

**Breaking it down (Bootstrap)**

1. `container-fluid` creates a container element that is 100% wide at
   all times. This means that at smaller window widths (e.g., on phones), your content will fill the full-width of the viewport.
2. `row` applies some basic flex-box parent styles that you can further tweak by setting its `justify-content` property to `center` at "large" (`lg`) window widths (with BS's utility class: `justify-content-lg-center`).
3. Since BS uses a 12-column grid by default, setting `col-12` on the `row`'s child element means that it will stretch to 100% of its parent's width. At large screen sizes, the above code says that the element should only stretch to fill 8/12's (or 2/3's) of its parent's horizontal dimensions (i.e., `col-lg-8`). Since we told the `row` element to center its flex-child at `lg` window widths, this layout will be horizontally centered.

Based on your screenshots, it doesn't appear that you want to constrain the width of your `header` (but I didn't see a `header` element in your markup). So that would need to be handled a bit differently.

As for your specific question, there are any number of ways you could accomplish this layout with Bootstrap (or without it), but maybe the above will get you started.

Comment: I dont have the header in this project.